# unresolvable parent POM at parent tag

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, parent-child, pom.xml

In the project i am working on i have the following pom.xml file. when right click and choose maven clean, i receive the following error

```
The project xx.xx.xx.xx.xx:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\xx.xx\xx\xx-api\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for de.bund.jki.sf.awanti:api:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.6.RELEASE from/to osgeo (https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/): Remote host terminated the handshake and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 10, column 10: SSL peer shut down incorrectly -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
```

i referrd to some questions in our website but it did not solve the issue. for example to add relativePath tag, it did not solve the issue.
please find the pom.xml file posted below. and please let me know how to fix it
the error eclipse generates is at the

```
<parent>
```

and it says:

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for xx.xx.xx.xx.xx:api:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.6.RELEASE from https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of osgeo has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.6.RELEASE from/to osgeo (https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/): Remote host terminated the handshake and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM
```

**code**:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>de.xx.xx.xx.xx</groupId>
<artifactId>api</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>    
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Try using to  add `<relativePath/>` in within the parent tag and furthermore `parent POM for de.bund.jki.sf.awanti:api:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: ` this looks like that the post is not representing the error message or vise versa...

Comment: @khmarbaise should i add <relativePath/> after opening and closing each tag??sorry i am new to maven and pom files

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
<parent>    
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

Comment: i tried it but it did not solve the problem

Comment: Exactly what I expected. The problem seemed to be located in the second part of my comment....

Comment: would you please tell me what do you expect the problem to be?

Comment: Please read: `furthermore parent POM for de.bund.jki.sf.awanti:api:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:  this looks like that the post is not representing`